# Ubuntu 11.10 Virtual-box Unity 3D not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

After struggling for four hours, I still cannot get Unity 3D of Gnome 3 to work on my VirtualBox - I have been pouring through Internet and forum posts but to no avail.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. VirtualBox 4.1.4r74921 on Windows 7
2. Installed Ubuntu Desktop 11.10 ( 32 bit )
3. Enabled 3D acceleration
4. Allocated 1.5GB of RAM
5. Allocated 50MB video memory (hope this is not the culprit)
6. Installed Guest edition 4.1.4
7. Did apt-get update and apt-get upgrade
8. Booted back in to Ubuntu - falls back to Unity 2D
9. Shared folder, mouse integration all works, so guest edition is properly installed
10. Tried the command and below is the output

    ```
    /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test –p

    OpenGL vendor string:   Mesa Project
    OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
    OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.11
    Not software rendered:    no
    Not blacklisted:          yes
    GLX fbconfig:             yes
    GLX texture from pixmap:  no
    GL npot or rect textures: yes
    GL vertex program:        yes
    GL fragment program:      yes
    GL vertex buffer object:  yes
    GL framebuffer object:    yes
    GL version is 1.4+:       yes
    Unity 3D supported:       no
    ```

I am trying to find what the "no" means but cannot find any good answers.

- Inter Core i5 processor
- 4GB of RAM on the host
- Display adapter: NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS

Is anyone else facing the same problem? If so, can you point me to a solution or any reference where I can find a solution?

Comment: I have steered clear of virtualising the ubuntu 11.* versions thus far. After the first 1 trashed one of my vbox partitions. I would recommend you ask in the ubuntu irc channel at freenode for help. They're very good at helping with these issues

Comment: This is not a programming question. Take a look at the [ubuntu stack exchange](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a SELinux error. See [this screencast](http://www.squidoo.com/enable-the-gnome-shell-in-fedora-16-and-virtual-box#module155995048) for instructions on how to run the Gnome Shell in VirtualBox (it's for Fedora 16, but the issue is probably the same).